# How I Fix in Dexterity Plone 4 error in Schema?

Tags: python, schema, plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

I'm writing this code for Dexterity in Plone 4, the code is simple, however, it causes a certain error, below we see the code and then an image of the error, there I explain what I did.

```
from plone.autoform import directives
from plone.namedfile import field as namedfile
from plone.supermodel import model
from z3c.form.browser.radio import RadioFieldWidget
from zope import schema
from zope.interface import invariant, Invalid
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleVocabulary
from zope.schema.vocabulary import SimpleTerm
from datetime import datetime

from projetime.ged import _

VocabularyDocumentType = SimpleVocabulary(
    [SimpleTerm(value=u'lawsuits', title=_(u'Lawsuits')),
     SimpleTerm(value=u'contracts', title=_(u'Contracts')),
     SimpleTerm(value=u'another', title=_(u'Another Docs'))]
)

def nowDateTime():
    return datetime.today()

class IDigitalFile(model.Schema):
    """Dexterity-Schema
    """

    directives.widget(documentType=RadioFieldWidget)
    documentType = schema.Choice(
        title=_(u"Document Type"),
        vocabulary=VocabularyDocumentType,
        required=True,
    )

    documentCod = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Document Cod."),
        description=_(u"The Document Cod must be have xxxx/yyyy"),
        required=False,
    )

    identification = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Identification"),
        description=_(u"Enter your indetification"),
        min_length = 11,
        required=False,
    )

    subject = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Subject"),
        required=True,
    )

    typeOf = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Type of Document"),
        required=False,
    )

    file = namedfile.NamedBlobFile(
        title=_(u"Digital Archive"),
        required=True,
    )

    directives.mode(auto="hidden")
    auto = schema.Bool(
        title=_(u"Upload via Script?"),
        required=True,
        default=False,
    )


    @invariant
    def DocumentTypeInvariant(data):
        if data.documentType == 'lawsuits':
            if not data.documentCod or not data.identification or not data.typeOf or not data.Description:
                raise Invalid(_(u"You choose Lawsuits, all fields are required!"))
        elif data.documentType == 'contracts':
            if not data.documentCod or not data.identification or not data.Description:
                raise Invalid(_(u"You choose Contracts, All fields with EXCEPTION of Type of Document are required"))
```

When I will create in Plone the object called DigitalFile, I start to fill in the fields, when all fields are filled,  I have this error before clicking submit:

[image: Module projetime.ged.content.digitalfile, line 87, in DocumentTypeInvariantModule; z3c.form.validator, line 164, in __getattr__;AttributeError: Description]

How I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `invariant` is defined in the `schema` and the `Description` Field is **not** in this schema, thus you cannot access it in the invariant.

You need something that take in account, that the Description field is defined in  a different schema.

You can solve your problem with a `Form validator`:
http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/schema-driven-forms/customising-form-behaviour/validation.html#validating-in-action-handlers

For this you need to register a custom edit/add form:
Check:http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/custom-add-and-edit-forms.html

This is all very well documented, for plone 4 and plone 5.

Comment: I assume that `IDublinCore.description` In the code above, it was called by `data.Description` like we do in page template. In this case I want to make the description required when selected `lawsuits` or `contracts`.

Comment: You got all form data in Form-validator, but you have a invariant, which is stuck to the schema you defined. `data` in the invariant is not the same as `data` in the form validator. You have to use a form validator.

Comment: This is new for me, 'cuz I'm newbie in development. Those codes of `edit/add form` will are put in another sctructure file or in the same file that I write in `content/digitafile.py`?